# how to select which button to select in alert message for IOS UIAutomation

Tags: ui-automation

How to click on alert message buttons when Alert has Yes and No Buttons.

And i tried the way like:

```
target.frontMostApp().alert().buttons()["buttonName"].tap();
target.frontMostApp().alert().buttons()["index"].tap();
```

And also Ui Automation click on either of the button and displays the below syn tax as:

```
target.frontMostApp().alert().cancelButtons().tap();
```

and its didnt work when i do it manually to click on default button.and also tried with the below ways also.

```
target.frontMostApp().alert().cancelButtons()["index/buttonname"].tap();
target.frontMostApp().alert().defaultButtons()["index/buttonname"].tap();
```

How to select the Yes button or NO button from the Alert message?

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh you need to use this code inside an onAlert.

Also you need to a second tap in a try catch block.

My code where is used to delete a row in a table and confirm an alert shown on the delete button.

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow() .tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()[0]
  .dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.03, y:0.44}, 
  endOffset:{x:0.81, y:0.50},duration:1}); 

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()[0]
  .buttons()[0].tap();


UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
    alert.tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.73, y:0.72}});
}

try {
    target.frontMostApp().alert().tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.72, y:0.78}});
}
catch (ex) {}
```